# Using bridge utils to connect two computers via Linux

Tags: linux, networking, routing, bridge

I have been using bridge utils previously to connect my network connected computers to a single interface on my Linux computer. The problem I'm having is when I installed a new Linux (with Slackware) the two connected computers cannot even ping each other. Basically the computers are connected as:

```
client - server - client
           |
       [Internet]
```

So I am trying to get the two clients to connect to each other. Both can access the Internet, firewalls are shut off at both clients when testing.

Internet is on eth0, and I have one bridge set up as

```
bridge name     interfaces
br0             eth1, eth2
```

`ip addr br0` and `ip route show` shows respectively

```
inet 10.0.0.1/24 brd 10.0.0.255
10.0.0.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1
```

So it seems to me like a call from my client should be routed directly to my br0 interface, which should get it right.

How do I configure my Slackware distro to route two network cable attached computers to be able to see eachother, preferably using bridge utils?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the firewall on the server disabled? It maybe that there are some firewall rules that are blocking the packets. Look at the output of iptables (must be run as root) and if you see anything other than ACCEPT rules/policies then they may be blocking things.

```
iptables -L
```

and

```
iptables -t nat -L
```

Comment: I figured it had something to do with the firewall. I'm using [Jay's Iptables Firewall](http://firewall-jay.sourceforge.net/) (yes, its not maintained, I know) since I never put myself trough learning iptables. This results in quite a few rules, but as far as I can see all "LAN rules" are allowed (the top LAN rules have ACCEPT in them). Is there any way I can "clear" the iptables to test whether or not it's the iptable rules that are the villain here?

Comment: "man iptables" is your friend :-)

Comment: But in any case try  iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT; iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT; iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT; iptables -F INPUT; iptables -F OUTPUT; iptables -F FORWARD;   You may also need to do the same with the nat tables but you should be able to work out what is needed there from the examples above.

Comment: @Richm: Well whaddayaknow. `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT` made the magic happen.. Now I just need to figure out how I can set this to LAN only..

Comment: When using bridge, is the traffic still handled as if it's coming from eth1 and not "from" br0? This might be the cause of why the traffic from eth1 stops at the server. According to fw-jay (mentioned earlier) eth1 and eth2 is down when the "commit" script is run, so no rules seem to be added for those interfaces. I made a diff of `iptables -L` and could see that my iptables had drop and not accept for the forward policy.

Comment: The behaviour of the bridging firewall code changed between the 2.4 and 2.6 kernel series. From memory 2.6.x will match the input against the br0 interface unless your iptables rules specify "-m physdev --physdev-in eth0" in which case it would match the physical input device. Of course you can swap eth0 for eth1 and --physdev-in for --physdev-out as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

If the two devices cannot ping each other it sounds like the bridge is not correctly setup. There is no ip protocol routing involved in the bridge. What is the output of *brctl show* ? That should show something like

```
$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.003018a46079       no              eth1
                                                        eth2
```

If both interfaces are not listed there then that needs correcting.

You may also like to try the `brctl showmacs br0` command and if STP (spanning tree protocol) was enabled above the `brctl showstp br0` command. The former should show the mac addresses of the two devices and the for the latter you should look to make sure that each port is in state *forwarding*

Given that you say that each can access the internet I assume that all of the interfaces have been brought up. If not the following should do that.

```
ip link set br0 up
ip link set eth0 up
ip link set eth1 up
ip link set eth2 up
```

Comment: `brctl show` displays the same as your output (with change in bridge id of course). showmacs displays the mac addresses of my clients and my connected interfaces, all four of them. All interfaces are up as displayed by `ip a show`.

Answer (score 2):

Check if ip fowarding is enabled on the server with the command

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
```

if this gives 0, do

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

as root on the server. If this helps, make the change permanent by editing /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: it prints `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`, so no dice unfortunately.